# Is there no problem in thinking of any motion of a rigid body as a composition of translational motion and rotation w.r.t center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

Sometimes when I work on mechanics problems, I wonder if this analysis is always valid.

Couldn't there be some motion of a rigid body that cannot be expressed as a composition of translational motion and rotation with respect to the center of mass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Euler's rotation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem) states that every rigid motion that leaves some point fixed is equivalent to a rotation about an axis running through that point. It is easy to see that every rigid motion can therefore be decomposed in the prescribed manner (*i.e.*, by first moving the centre of mass to its new location).